# How to filter list item list in Python

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
[('1',{'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':True, 'c': 'C'}),('2',{'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':False, 'c': 'C'})]
```

How do I filter this list using list comprehension, so I get a new list that has only `'active':True,`

I've tried list comprehension like so:

```
[item for item in list if item.active==True]
```

but I ended up having AttributeError

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'active'
```

Comment: Have you done a Python tutorial? Dict access is done through indexing, not attributes. 
Try the official tutorial; here's the relevant part: [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You'll also need to do tuple indexing. As well, that error message doesn't match that code. It should say `'tuple' object`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the snippet you provided, if you run the code you're actually getting this error:

```py
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'active'
```

The main reason for that is that each `item` in your list comprehension is a tuple `('1',{'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':True, 'c': 'C'})` is the first one and `('2',{'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':False, 'c': 'C'})` is the second one. If you want to access the `active`, you must first access the SECOND element of your tuple (the dict containing the `active` key) and THEN filter by it.

Here's a sample code:

```py
new_list = [item for item in list if item[1]["active"] == True]
```

However, I'll advise that if you can, you should definitely use a better data-structure to represent this data. Something like:

```py
[{'id': 1, 'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':True, 'c': 'C'}, {'id': 2, 'a':'A','b':'B', 'active':False, 'c': 'C'}]
```

is probably better (but could be improved as well). For this code, the list comprehension is like so:

```py
new_list = [item for item in list if item["active"] == True]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:
[item for item in l if item[1]['active']]

you get that error because you are looking for active in the first element which is '1'. Searching in item[1] searches in the tuple.